# is there any way to avoid to get videos with "sign in to confirm your age" in search result?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

if i'm not logged in youtube, when we click to play in certains videos we get the message "Sign in to confirm your age".
In the page of these videos,  we have this just over Category:
"notice Age-restricted video (based on Community Guidelines)".

my question is: as we can in a search set some parameters about what videos we are searching, like duration, etc... is there any way to avoid this kind of videos in the search result?

Sample of video with age-restriction:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txKsYpYtxq4

(must be NOT logged)

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Looking for the info about this video i get this info:

Response

```
{  
   "kind":"youtube#videoListResponse",
   "etag":"\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/QZtBV_JWvHNT9ClkQ0eYuktRtbA\"",
   "pageInfo":{  
      "totalResults":1,
      "resultsPerPage":1
   },
   "items":[  
      {  
         "kind":"youtube#video",
         "etag":"\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/f87eqCBLTBWB7VX3U7MeBERp-P0\"",
         "id":"txKsYpYtxq4",
         "snippet":{  
            "publishedAt":"2017-05-30T19:39:53.000Z",
            "channelId":"UCcepdparhCfkNMZGzhKyZYA",
            "title":"DJ Scuff - Plakiti (Pla Pla) NUEVA VAINA",
            "description":"PARA CONTRATACIONES: 809-907-4426 O 646-932-3378\n\nMP3: https://app.box.com/s/iv4bnfjbdo48xt4c6a2b0dip5nydzh3s",
            "thumbnails":{  
               "default":{  
                  "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/txKsYpYtxq4/default.jpg",
                  "width":120,
                  "height":90
               },
               "medium":{  
                  "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/txKsYpYtxq4/mqdefault.jpg",
                  "width":320,
                  "height":180
               },
               "high":{  
                  "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/txKsYpYtxq4/hqdefault.jpg",
                  "width":480,
                  "height":360
               },
               "standard":{  
                  "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/txKsYpYtxq4/sddefault.jpg",
                  "width":640,
                  "height":480
               },
               "maxres":{  
                  "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/txKsYpYtxq4/maxresdefault.jpg",
                  "width":1280,
                  "height":720
               }
            },
            "channelTitle":"djscuff",
            "tags":[  
               "dj",
               "scuff",
               "mezcla",
               "fiesta",
               "urbano",
               "dembow",
               "latino",
               "latin",
               "party",
               "plakiti",
               "nueva",
               "vaina"
            ],
            "categoryId":"10",
            "liveBroadcastContent":"none",
            "localized":{  
               "title":"DJ Scuff - Plakiti (Pla Pla) NUEVA VAINA",
               "description":"PARA CONTRATACIONES: 809-907-4426 O 646-932-3378\n\nMP3: https://app.box.com/s/iv4bnfjbdo48xt4c6a2b0dip5nydzh3s"
            }
         },
         "contentDetails":{  
            "duration":"PT2M15S",
            "dimension":"2d",
            "definition":"hd",
            "caption":"false",
            "licensedContent":true,
            "contentRating":{  
               "ytRating":"ytAgeRestricted"
            },
            "projection":"rectangular"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

at the bottom i can see:

> "contentRating": {
>        "ytRating": "ytAgeRestricted"
>       }

when i do a search for this particular video with this code:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=txKsYpYtxq4&key=MY_KEY
```

i get the videos matching query.

The question is: is there any parameter for use in order to exclude all the videos with contentRating "ytAgeRestricted"?

Or the unique way is to ask one by one after the search?

Comment: have you readed the question, oh big god of stackoverflow? you invest the time with this kind of comments? help people or let people ask for help

Comment: Should I answer this or not??

Comment: sorry, i dont understand. Please, if you can help, give answer!

Comment: **i'm not logged in youtube**  @PeterPam your question appears to be about the YouTube application.  Stack overflow is a programming site.  If your question is in fact programming related please edit your question include the code you are using and describe any issues you are having with your application.    You should only be using the API tags if you are actually using an API in your own project.

Comment: USE :  `https://www.nsfwyoutube.com/watch?v=txKsYpYtxq4`  OR  `https://www.youtuberepeat.com/watch?v=txKsYpYtxq4` OR  `https://www.youtube.com/embed/txKsYpYtxq4` But yes this type of questions are not entertained here

Comment: i understand your comments. but nobody read all the text i wrote. My question is if there is any parameter in API in order to avoid get this kind of videos  in results of a search with API.

Comment: @PeterPam until you edit your question and incldue the code you are using to search youtube we can not help you.  I would love to help you but i cant test what i cant see.  You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: oK. Thanks very much. I will update the question with my progress.

Answer (score 0):

The q parm in in the [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method does a full text search on the title and description of the video.

> q  string
>
> The q parameter specifies the query term to search for.
>
> Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing. Similarly, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing" but not "fishing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing -fishing. Note that the pipe character must be URL-escaped when it is sent in your API request. The URL-escaped value for the pipe character is %7C.

The [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)  method does not have a parameter for restricting the ytAgeRestricted.  There is however a method called safeSearch which may work I have not been able to find any information on exactly what this method is intended for it has something to do with the PG rating i suspect

IMO this could be useful you may want to consider adding this as a feature request [Youtube issue forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803)